# JSCH read from input stream hangs from time to time

Tags: jsch

I'm using jsch-0.1.53.

In order to execute a command and return it's output, I wrote the next block of code:

```
    @Override
public String executeAndGetOutput(CheckPointSSHConnection connection, String command) throws IOException , JSchException{
    logger.debug("Executing command \"" + command + "\"");
    StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();
    ChannelExec channel = null;
    InputStream in=null;
    InputStream errStream=null;
    try {
        Session session = connection.getSession();
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");//only shell
         in = channel.getInputStream();
        errStream = channel.getErrStream();
        channel.setCommand(command);
        channel.connect(10000);
        String errInStr = StringUtils.toString(errStream);
        String inStr = StringUtils.toString(in);
        return inStr+errInStr;
    } finally {
        IOUtils.close(in);
        IOUtils.close(errStream);
        if (channel != null) {
            try {
                channel.disconnect();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                logger.warn("An exception occured while trying to close ssh chanel. Message:",
                        throwable.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that from time to time, reading the `errStream` just hangs and blocking the thread.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The command that I'm executing is `load_indicators --add -a detect -i /tmp/sample_file.csv` , it's Checkpoint CLI

Comment: It would be helpful to know what command(s) you're running when it hangs.

Comment: I don't really understand why it matters, but I added the command at the bottom.